# Using .net Framework Assemblies in Universal Apps

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-10-universal

Is there a Way to use Assemblies developed for ".net Framework" in Windows Universal Apps.

When I try to add a Reference to such an Assembly like e.g. "Fast Report" I get an Error Message that the Assembly is Developed for ".net Framework" and the Project im in is ".net Core"

Is there any Way to use such Assemblies in .net Core Projects?

Comment: Please include a repro (e.g. steps to create this issue through Visual Studio, or perhaps the resulting project files).

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Standard 2.0 & .NET Core 2.0 and there is support for using libraries built for .NET Framework <= 4.6.1.

When .NET Standard 2.0 support for UWP will be released (announced for later in 2017), this will be possible.

However, it does not guarantee that all libraries will work. There is support for a lot of APIs but if the library uses API (classes, methods, assemblies, ...) that is not available, it will cause an exception at run-time.